# Loading data from different collection based on parameter

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generics, odata

I'm using OData Connected Service to consume OData. In my endpoint, there are many collections, so in order to avoid spaghetti code I thought I would execute my code with a parameter which would tell, which collection to use.

Here's a code snippet of what I'm doing for single collection:

```
 var ctx = new ODataService(new Uri("http://urlofodataendpoint/OData/"));
            ctx.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 
            ctx.Format.UseJson();

            var query = from f in ctx.Files
                        select new File
                        {
                            Title = f.Title
                        };
            DataServiceCollection<File> files = new DataServiceCollection<File>(query);

            while (files.Continuation != null)
                files.Load(ctx.Execute(files.Continuation));


            foreach (var f in files)
            {
                //do something for each File

            }
```

In this case, Files is collection of type of File. I would like to do this code for every collection. Of course, each collection has a different type in it.
Here's what I tried:

```
string nameOfCollection = "Files";
            var ctx = new ODataService(new Uri("https://urlofodataendpoint/OData/"));
            ctx.Credentials = new System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 
            ctx.Format.UseJson();


            dynamic type = ctx.Links;
            PropertyInfo[] PI = ctx.GetType().GetProperties();

            for(int i=0; i<PI.Count();i++)
            {
                if (PI[i].Name == nameOfCollection )
                    type = PI[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine(type);

            //Type itemtype = type.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();

            var query = from f in ((IEnumerable<Type>)type).Cast<dynamic>()
                        select f;

            DataServiceCollection <dynamic> files = new DataServiceCollection<File>(query);

            while (files.Continuation != null)
                files.Load(ctx.Execute(files.Continuation));
```

Unfortunately the

```
var query = from f in ((IEnumerable<Type>)type).Cast<dynamic>()
                        select f;
```

part fails with

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Type]'.'

Also the part when I want to assign DataServiceCollection doesn't work:

> Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'

How can I chose the collection dynamically and query it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got invalid cast when you try to convert variable type to `IEnumerable<Type>`.

Consider change this code:

```
var query = from f in ((IEnumerable<Type>)type).Cast<dynamic>()
                    select f;
```

to:

```
var query = from f in ((IEnumerable)type.GetValue(ctx)).Cast<dynamic>()
                    select f;
```

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work because I used System.Collections.Generics, but it does now so thank you! Now

var query = from f in ((IEnumerable)type).Cast<dynamic>()
                        select f;

throws exception
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.'

so I guess i initiated it wronlgy in for loop. How should I map it to collection called "Files" then?

Comment: Now, looking at your for loop, I saw what's can happening. Try to change your linq to `var query = from f in ((IEnumerable)type.GetValue(ctx)).Cast<dynamic>() select f;`